# Parsing xml response in JAVA

Tags: java, parsing, xml-parsing

I have a xml file which looks as below. I want to parse this xml and display the result as PASS if `<PROCESSED>1</PROCESSED>` is having the value as `1` and the `<STATE>Finished</STATE>` is showing as `Finished.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE SCAN_LIST_OUTPUT SYSTEM "https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/scan/scan_list_output.dtd">
<SCAN_LIST_OUTPUT>
    <RESPONSE>
        <DATETIME>2017-06-12T07:28:46Z</DATETIME>
        <SCAN_LIST>
            <SCAN>
                <ID>3332486</ID>
                <REF>compliance/1347341337.35943</REF>
                <TYPE>Scheduled</TYPE>
                <TITLE><![CDATA[MY PC Scan]]></TITLE>
                <USER_LOGIN>USER</USER_LOGIN>
                <LAUNCH_DATETIME>2017-06-13T07:30:09Z</LAUNCH_DATETIME>
                <DURATION>00:06:29</DURATION>
                <PROCESSED>1</PROCESSED>
                <STATUS>
                    <STATE>Finished</STATE>
                </STATUS>
                <TARGET><![CDATA[10.10.25.50]]></TARGET>
            </SCAN>
        </SCAN_LIST>
    </RESPONSE>
</SCAN_LIST_OUTPUT>
```

Please let me know how this can be done using Java.

Comment: You can use XML parser for this. The simplest one is DOMParser or you can use SAXParser for the same.

Comment: You can use a library like JAXB to parse an xml file, if all the xml files have an defined structure than you can map an appropriate class for marshaling the file.

Comment: Can you please suggest on how  `SAXParser` will be used to parse the above xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the sample implementation for SAXParser :

You first need to create a Handler in order to use SAXParser and for more information you can visit link : https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

```
class ReadXMLFile {

    String processed, state;

    public void parseXml() {
        try {

            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            StringReader sr = new StringReader("<SCAN_LIST_OUTPUT>     <RESPONSE>         <DATETIME>2017-06-12T07:28:46Z</DATETIME>         <SCAN_LIST>             <SCAN>                 <ID>3332486</ID>                 <REF>compliance/1347341337.35943</REF>                 <TYPE>Scheduled</TYPE>                 <TITLE><![CDATA[MY PC Scan]]></TITLE>                 <USER_LOGIN>USER</USER_LOGIN>                 <LAUNCH_DATETIME>2017-06-13T07:30:09Z</LAUNCH_DATETIME>                 <DURATION>00:06:29</DURATION>                 <PROCESSED>1</PROCESSED>                 <STATUS>                     <STATE>Finished</STATE>                 </STATUS>                 <TARGET><![CDATA[10.10.25.50]]></TARGET>             </SCAN>         </SCAN_LIST>     </RESPONSE> </SCAN_LIST_OUTPUT>");
            //Reader sr = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes()), "UTF-8");
            InputSource is = new InputSource(sr);
            saxParser.parse(is, new SampleHandler());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        ReadXMLFile obj = new ReadXMLFile();
        obj.parseXml();
        System.out.println(obj.processed);
        System.out.println(obj.state);

    }

    private class SampleHandler extends DefaultHandler {

        boolean bprocessed = false;
        boolean bstate = false;


        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("PROCESSED")) {
                bprocessed = true;
            }

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("STATE")) {
                bstate = true;
            }
        }

        public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                String qName) throws SAXException {
        }

        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

            if (bprocessed) {
                processed = new String(ch, start, length);
                bprocessed = false;
            }

            if (bstate) {
                state = new String(ch, start, length);
                bstate = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Please note this is sample implementation and you may need to change this as per your need.**

Comment: thanks for your example. I am using this example to do parsing http://www.journaldev.com/1198/java-sax-parser-example   Do I need to create class for `scan_list` if I use this example?

Comment: No you don't need to, because we are extracting only two fields you require for processing. Although if you need to parse a large xml file then the example you have mentioned is the preferred way to go. .

Comment: okay thanks. Also, in your `StringReader` object you are passing string. How can i pass location of the xml file directly in the `StringReader` object? Something like `/Users/pankaj/scan.xml`

Comment: Check the link I had provided. You can directly pass the link of location of file instead to StringReader e.g : `** saxParser.parse("c:\\file.xml", handler);**`

Comment: I am running this and `System.out.println(obj.processed)` is returning `null` It should not be null

Comment: Output is returning `null` It should not be null. SAX Parser raises `UnknownHostException` because it is trying to access this DTD online

Comment: Yes, that's the issue, your internal network is blocking that site either remove that part from XML or use your proxy settings.

Comment: I have tried to include `factory.setValidating(false);` but it doesn't seem to work. It is not allowed to remove DTD portion from the xml

Comment: use `factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);` .

Comment: Getting error `org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature 'http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalida‌​ting/load-external-d‌​td' is not recognized.`

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: you mean IntelliJ version?

Answer (score 0):

Using XPath and VTD-XML it is a 10-line app.

```
import com.ximpleware.*;

public class testData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws VTDException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if (!vg.parseFile("d:\\xml\\scan_input.xml", false))
            return ;
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        String xpath = "/SCAN_LIST_OUTPUT/RESPONSE/SCAN_LIST/SCAN/PROCESSED=1 "+
                       "and /SCAN_LIST_OUTPUT/RESPONSE/SCAN_LIST/SCAN/STATUS/STATE='Finished' ";
        ap.selectXPath(xpath);
        if (ap.evalXPathToBoolean())
            System.out.println("pass");
    }

}
```